# CKModifySubscriptionsOperation succeeds, but changes are not stored in iCloud

Tags: ios, swift, async-await, cloudkit, subscription

*EDIT:*
The problem described below occurs when subscriptions should be created, modified or deleted in the iCloud shared or public databases. My code works correctly when the private database is used.
*End of edit.*

**Setup:**

My app uses iCloud subscriptions that are created, modified and deleted using `CKModifySubscriptionsOperation`.
During refactoring of the code, I changed the required subscriptions, so that old subscriptions have to be deleted, and new ones to be saved. This is the code used:

```
static func modifySubscriptions(database: CKDatabase, 
                                subscriptionsToSave: [CKSubscription]?, 
                                andDeletesubscriptionIDsToDelete: [String]?) async throws -> ([CKSubscription]?, [String]?) {
    return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { (continuation: CheckedContinuation<([CKSubscription]?, [String]?), Error>) in
        let op = CKModifySubscriptionsOperation(subscriptionsToSave: subscriptionsToSave, subscriptionIDsToDelete: subscriptionIDsToDelete)
        op.qualityOfService = .utility
        
        op.modifySubscriptionsResultBlock = { result in
            switch result {
                case .success:
                    continuation.resume(returning: (subscriptionsToSave, subscriptionIDsToDelete))
                case .failure(let error):
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error)
            }
        }
        
        database.add(op)
    }
```

In the iCloud shared database of the development environment, there are 2 new subscriptions to be saved and one existing to be deleted.

**Problem:**

The code runs successful, i.e. `case .success` is called with the correct parameters.
However the modifications are not persisted.
This can be seen in the Dashboard by displaying the subscriptions in the shared database. The CloudKit Logs show a subscription modify operation initiated by my iPhone with a request size of 458 and a response size of 0 (which is not very helpful).
That the modifications are not persisted can also be seen by running the app again (it checks which subscriptions exist, and adds or removes subscriptions only when required).

**Question:**

How to check what went wrong?

PS: I have checked [this post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/45421) and [this post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/76893), but they don't apply since there the operation fails in contrast to my situation.